# MS Teams Bot - task/fetch URL not loading in web/desktop app but loading in android app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to display an URL upon **invoke (task/fetch)** via MS Teams bot. The URL is loading and working perfectly fine on android/ios app. But it is not loading at all in web/desktop app. The app has been in production for some time now and I recently updated the app manifest with valid domains for making the URLs load in Teams.

Also I tried the same manifest/backend with another test app and URLs are loading fine in web/mobile app. Not sure what am I missing here.

Please find below my task/fetch response and manifest details.

task/fetch response

```
{
  "task": {
    "type": "continue",
    "value": {
      "title": "Task Module Test",
      "height": 1200,
      "width": 1000,
      "url": "https://www.contoso.com/msteams/taskmodules/newcustomer",
      "fallbackUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/msteams/taskmodules/newcustomer"
    }
  }
}
```

My App Manifest (have edited some sensitive info but the structure of the manifest is intact)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "showLoadingIndicator": true,
  "id": "some-id",
  "packageName": "com.example.bots.msteams",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Test",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/policy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/terms"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Test Short",
    "full": "Test Long"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Short desc",
    "full": "Long desc"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "some-id",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ],
      "supportsFiles": true,
      "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "www.contoso.com"
  ]
}
```

[URL successfully loading on Phone app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwchQ.png)

[URL not loading on web/desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQDuh.png)

Happy to provide any other info if needed!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the fix (but I have no clue why it works). I removed **showLoadingIndicator** property from the manifest and the URLs are loading fine now.

I couldn't find much help on what that property does from MS docs.

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you found the solution and thanks for posting it back to help other community members.

When you set `showLoadingIndicator` to `true`, as a mandatory step you need to call `microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess()` to notify Teams that your app has successfully loaded.

The behavior on mobile clients is not configurable through the native loading indicator property. Mobile clients show this indicator by default across content pages and iframe-based task modules.

Here is documentation on [Show Loading Indicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/content-page#show-a-native-loading-indicator).